# SBT uses too much ram

Tags: sbt

I'm using sbt for a liftweb development, but it's using 1.2 GB of ram, and sometimes it throws *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space*, is it normal that sbt uses this amount of ram?

Answer (score 2):

You can

```
export SBT_OPTS="-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=512M"
```

Wrote about it in http://samwize.com/2012/10/18/scala-tutorial-part-ii/.